Solve for $x = \cot(x/2)$, where $x$ is between $0$ and $\pi$
I am attempting to solve for the function with $x$ being some angle expressed in radians between $0$ and $\pi$:
$$x = \cot(x/2).$$
I was able to graph it on Desmos, but I am unsure how to mathematically get the answer. It seems to me that while I might be able to manipulate $\cot$ into other trigonometric identities, it is useless if I can't convert it to a concrete value - which I can't do until I know $x$. However, I don't know what $x$ is until I am able to solve the equality.

AFAIK, there's no closed form solution, just the numerical approximation $x \approx 1.3065423741888063$.

This is a [tag:transcendental-equations] which likely has no closed form. Are you looking for a exact (sum/integral) or numerical solution?

I was looking for exact, thank you for clarifying that there's likely no closed form solution.

There is an exact solution in terms of an infinite summation.
